# Python: Function Returning Duplicate Values

Tags: python, function, pandas, duplicates

So I created a test dataset that looks like this

```
INDEX YEAR_ID GAME_ID BAT_TEAM_ID INN_CT EVENT_CD INN_PA_CT wBB   wHBP  w1B
0     2016    1       ANN         1      1        0         0.691 0.721 0.878
1     2016    1       ANN         1      3        1         0.691 0.721 0.878
2     2016    1       ANN         2      3        0         0.691 0.721 0.878
3     2016    1       ANN         2      1        1         0.691 0.721 0.878
4     2016    1       CLE         2      2        0         0.691 0.721 0.878
5     2016    1       CLE         2      2        1         0.691 0.721 0.878
6     2016    2       KCA         1      1        0         0.691 0.721 0.878
7     2016    2       KCA         1      1        1         0.691 0.721 0.878
8     2016    2       KCA         1      3        2         0.691 0.721 0.878
9     2016    2       KCA         1      2        3         0.691 0.721 0.878
10    2016    2       TEX         1      1        0         0.691 0.721 0.878
11    2016    2       TEX         1      1        1         0.691 0.721 0.878
12    2016    2       TEX         1      2        2         0.691 0.721 0.878
13    2016    2       TEX         1      1        3         0.691 0.721 0.878
14    2016    2       KCA         2      2        0         0.691 0.721 0.878
15    2016    2       KCA         2      2        1         0.691 0.721 0.878
```

and I've defined a function to calculate some statistic:

```
def woba(x):
    return ((((x['EVENT_CD'] == 1).sum() * x['wBB']) +
             ((x['EVENT_CD'] == 2).sum() * x['wHBP']) +
             ((x['EVENT_CD'] == 3).sum() * x['w1B'])) / (x['INN_PA_CT'].max()))

stat = df.groupby(['BAT_TEAM_ID', 'GAME_ID', 'INN_CT']).apply(woba)
stat = stat.reset_index(level = ['BAT_TEAM_ID', 'GAME_ID', 'INN_CT'])
stat.columns = ['BAT_TEAM_ID', 'GAME_ID', 'INN_CT', 'wOBA']
```

and the function works, it returns the values I want, but for some reason there are duplicates in the result

```
INDEX BAT_TEAM_ID GAME_ID INN_CT wOBA
0     ANN         1       1      1.569
1     ANN         1       1      1.569
2     ANN         1       2      1.569
3     ANN         1       2      1.569
4     CLE         1       2      1.442
5     CLE         1       2      1.442
6     KCA         2       1      0.993666667
7     KCA         2       1      0.993666667
8     KCA         2       1      0.993666667
9     KCA         2       1      0.993666667
14    KCA         2       2      1.442
15    KCA         2       2      1.442
10    TEX         2       1      0.931333333
11    TEX         2       1      0.931333333
12    TEX         2       1      0.931333333
13    TEX         2       1      0.931333333
```

when there should only be 6 rows.

What went wrong, or how do I fix this?

Comment: Um, why do you think it should only be 6 rows? you `.apply` a function that returns a data-frame, and that is aggregated, and as you can see in your data, `wBB   wHBP  w1B` are repeated...

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the stat for each team per game, per inning. Index 0 and 1 are the same value for the same team, game, and inning, and so are index 2 and 3, and so forth, the most duplicates being indexes 6-9. `wBB, wHBP, and w1B` are weights for different actions, and they change year-by-year so they were merged with the dataframe for the calculation.

Comment: Well, I don't know what your function is doing, it might be fixable at that level, but you could always add a `.drop_duplicates()`

Comment: So, `df.groupby(['BAT_TEAM_ID', 'GAME_ID', 'INN_CT']).apply(woba).reset_index(level = ['BAT_TEAM_ID', 'GAME_ID', 'INN_CT']).drop_duplicates()`

Comment: Perfect, @juanpa.arrivillaga. The solution worked perfectly!

Comment: There are many ways to skin this cat.  The problem is that your formula is returning a series rather than a scalar value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your formula is not returning a single scalar number but it is returning a series because your group has multiple values(the same number multiple times) for wBB, wHBP, and w1B.

One way to fix this is to add .max() after each of these to get only one value, since that value is the same in the group, you can use .max() or .first().

Or you can simply max the result.

```
def woba(x):
    result = ((((x['EVENT_CD'] == 1).sum() * x['wBB']) +
             ((x['EVENT_CD'] == 2).sum() * x['wHBP']) +
             ((x['EVENT_CD'] == 3).sum() * x['w1B'])) / (x['INN_PA_CT'].max()))
    return result.max()

df.groupby(['BAT_TEAM_ID', 'GAME_ID', 'INN_CT']).apply(lambda x: woba(x))
```

Output:

```
BAT_TEAM_ID  GAME_ID  INN_CT
ANN          1        1         1.569000
                      2         1.569000
CLE          1        2         1.442000
KCA          2        1         0.993667
                      2         1.442000
TEX          2        1         0.931333
dtype: float64
```